# Submit button not submitting

Tags: javascript, validation, button

I have a simple html login form which is validated with javascript before its submitted. When I attempt to submit the form with the validation conditions unmet I get my validation alerts as per usual. However when they are met the submit button becomes unresponsive.

Here's the html code for the form:

```
<form action="staff_login_process.php" class="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validLog()">

            <fieldset>

            <div id="apply_width">

                    <div id="field_area">

                            <h2 class="white">Login</h2>

                                <label for="username">Username<span>*</span>
                                </label> <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="username" class="float_right" />

                                <label for="password">Password<span>*</span>
                                </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="float_right" />
                                <a class="red" href="">Forgot Password</a>

                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />

            </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

and here's the Javascript code which takes care of the validation:

```
function validLog() {

var username = document.getElementById('username');
var password = document.getElementById('password');


if(notEmpty(username, "Please enter username")){
    if(notEmpty(password, "Please enter password")){
    }
}

return false;

} 

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value.length == 0){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I'm at a loss for what to try to get this working and can't spot where I've gone wrong here so any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validLog()` function ALWAYS returns `false`

Change

```
if(notEmpty(username, "Please enter username")){
    if(notEmpty(password, "Please enter password")) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: Not the exact answer but a push in the right direction! Got it working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

since `notEmpty` function return itself `true` or `false`, try simply

```
function validLog() {

   var username = document.getElementById('username'),
       password = document.getElementById('password');

   return notEmpty(username, "Please enter username") 
       && notEmpty(password, "Please enter password");
}
```

so the form will be submitted if both your values are not empty